# Why does this Android app validate email field on every character change and not just when the Save button is pressed?

Tags: design

There's this [sample repository](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing), which showcases different Android testing practices. One of the apps is [android-testing/unit/BasicSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/tree/master/unit/BasicSample), which is very simple and, among other things, checks the email field and for that purpose adds a listener like this:

```
mEmailText.addTextChangedListener(mEmailValidator);
```

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/923a02c2bee18e6315c5a71c8352a4c252cfa862/unit/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/testing/unittesting/BasicSample/MainActivity.java#L68

And then on save it checks

```
     if (!mEmailValidator.isValid()) {  
                 mEmailText.setError("Invalid email");
      }
```

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/923a02c2bee18e6315c5a71c8352a4c252cfa862/unit/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/testing/unittesting/BasicSample/MainActivity.java#L95

Why not just have a simple utility class which will perform this check only when the Save button is pressed and not on each character change?

Comment: see [Should a question that is meaningless without viewing an external link be closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266909/839601)

Comment: ...also, please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53159537/why-does-basicsample-validate-email-field-on-every-character-change-and-not-just "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Because it can.**

It's not overly taxing for the app to do this.

Perhaps there are other places where emails are validated, with UI that responds to the validation status changing. Having just one `EmailValidator` that listens to `TextChange` events and produces `ValidationChange` events is better than duplicating half of that work for a single check.